# why does this constructor call another with no arguments?

Tags: c++, constructor

I'm trying to create two simple classes, but this code doesn't compile for some reason. It's saying I'm calling point::point with no arguments, but the only time I call point::point is in the main function ,and I do call it with arguments there.

When debugging, I found it's the constructor for string_two_points that is calling the constructor for point.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
class point{
public:
    int x;
    int y;
    point(int x, int y): x(x),y(y){};
    point(const point & c): x(c.x), y(c.y) {}; 
    };

class string_two_points{ 
public:
    string type;
    point x;
    point y;
    string_two_points(string type, point & xc):type(type){
        x=xc;
    };
    string_two_points(string type, point & xc, point & yc):type(type){
        x=xc;
        y=yc;
    };

};

int main(){
    point a =  point(2,3);
    point b =  point(3,4);
    string_two_points x = string_two_points(string("abc"),a,b);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `string_two_points` has `point x;` as a member. So when you construct a `string_two_points`, it constructs `x` which involves calling `x`'s constructor.

Comment: You need to tell us where the compiler complaint occurs.  ctors are often called for reasons you did not explicitly code.  You show two ctors in point.  The compiler probably has provided several others, including a default ctor.

Comment: @DOUGLASO.MOEN compiler does not provide a default constructor if there is a user-provided constructor

Comment: @M.M An interesting idea.  Still, it is trivial to disallow a default ctor ... just to know (by a new error) that it is being used, and where

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
string_two_points(string type, point & xc):type(type){
```

This constructor is not initializing `point y`, so it gets default initialized by calling the default parameterless constructor `point::point` (which doesn't exist).

Answer (score 0):

Both the constructors of `string_two_points` try to invoke the default constructor of `point` for `x` and `y` and then assign them something.
It fails because `point()` doesn't exist as a constructor, as correctly mentioned by the compiler.

Answer (score 0):

Since class `string_two_points` has `point` members named `x` and `y`, any initialization of `string_two_points` must include an initialization of `x` and `y`.  Since you didn't describe how to initialize them in the constructors' member initializer lists, the compiler automatically added default initializations, as though you had written

```
string_two_points(string type, point & xc):type(type), x(), y() {
    x=xc;
};
```

Note `x=xc;` is not an initialization, it's an assignment which happens after initialization is complete.

Comment: depending on the details of the class, `x()` could be value-initialization which can have different behaviour to default-initialization

Answer (score 0):

Since `string_two_points` has two members of type `point`, and in neither constructor are both given a default value, the compiler needs to initialize them. In order to do that it tries to call the default, parameterless constructor. Since that doesn't exist, that generates an error.

You can fix that by initializing the members in each constructor:

```
class string_two_points
{
public:
    string type;
    point x;
    point y;
    string_two_points(string type, point & xc)
    : type(type), x(xc), y(0, 0)
    {
    };

    string_two_points(string type, point& xc, point& yc)
    : type(type), x(xc), y(yc)
    {
    };
};
```